# Using the Parse Template transformer with an array in the data

Tags: mule

I'm a newbie to Mulesoft, and I'm looking to transform a Json object into an XML object via the Parse Template transformer. Straight forward enough, however, what is the appropriate approach when the Json object has an array with an undetermined number of elements?

For example, if I have a JSON object that looks like

> { "name" : "Methusela",
>    "hobbies: [
>      "name": "guitar",
>      "name": "cooking",
>      "name": "someting",
>   ...
>   ]}

where the number of hobbies is unknown at runtime
and my xml template looks like:

```
<Person>
<Name>#[payload.name]</Name>
<Hobbies>
    <!- What should this bit look like -->
</Hobbies>
```

So - my question is how should I approach the conversion of the open ended JSON array to XML?

Note that we are currently exploring the community edition and therefore don't have access to the data mapping functionality available through the enterprise edition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally, to transform a Json object into an XML object, by using Community edition, I will use: *JSON to Object* and *Object to XML* transformers.

However, to transform it using *Parse Template* I will utilize Mule Expression Language (MEL). For example:

```
<Person>
<Name>#[json:name]</Name>
<Hobbies>
#[
    org.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject(payload.toString());
    org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.get("hobbies");
    String hobbies = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        hobbies += "<Name>" + jsonArray.get(i).getString("name") + "</Name>";
    }
    hobbies;
]
</Hobbies>
</Person>
```

Comment: Hi @Sulthony Thanks for the response. We can't use the default transformers directly as the schemas between the two aren't the same. Your solution might work tho I'd rather not have to do any string concatenation to build up the node. Is it possible to declare an iteration variable and call that in the loop? Also, the payload type at this stage is LinkedHashMap, so I wonder if that changes your proposed solution

Comment: You can replace the *String concatenation* with *XML Parser*. By using MEL you can write the transformation code based on your need. My answer just to show the idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In parse template you can use simple javascript loop:

```
for(i=0;i<#[payload.Hobbies].length;i++){
document.getElementById('Id').innerHtml += #[payload.Hobbies][i] 
}
```